# failure : gradle clean build

Tags: bitcoinj, compiling

First time. Wanting to learn / test / review / contribute.
Ubuntu - 22.04, openJDK 19.0.2, Gradle 8.1

I get the following error:

```
gradle clean build
Including wallettemplate because Gradle 8.1
Including integration-test because Gradle 8.1

> Configure project :
Warning: Using com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.18 because Gradle 8.1

> Configure project :bitcoinj-core
Adding 'testOnJdk8' task, because Gradle 8.1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/hem/Source/bitcoinj/core/build.gradle' line: 101

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':bitcoinj-core'.
> Could not set unknown property 'classifier' for task ':bitcoinj-core:javadocJar' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.
...

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
```

I did replace "classifier" with "archiveClassifier".

I get

```
> Task :bitcoinj-core:processResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':bitcoinj-core:processResources' (type 'ProcessResources').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/home/hem/Source/bitcoinj/core/src/main/resources'.
    
    Reason: Task ':bitcoinj-core:processResources' uses this output of task ':bitcoinj-core:generateProto' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
```

Am I doing this wrong. Is the mater branch not build able with latest gradle?